# Difference between index and data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, events, indexing

It's a bit hard to know what's going on `event.data.x` methods.

Would you tell me what's event.data.x exactly refers below this code?

I mostly understood how the code works such as function stuctures, parameters, methods except this `function(event)` part.

Is it the number of function that has parameter named `event`?

It would be great if you explain those using easy words.

plus: Is there any difference between index and data at Jquery??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").each(function(i) {
    $(this).on("click", {
      x: i
    }, function(event) {
      alert("The " + $(this).index() + ". paragraph has data: " + event.data.x);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: `event.data.x` is the value you provide to the `click` event from the `each()` loop, as such it's the index of the element within the selected collection of `p` elemnts.

Comment: `Is there any difference between index and data at Jquery` Yes. `event.data.x` will be the index within the `p` collection you select. `$(this).index()` will be the index of the current element within its parent element. Given your HTML example, the numbers will be the same. Put any element first in the DOM, and they will not be.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Appreciated for detail answering. :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).index()` returns the index of the element that you clicked on in its container element.

`event.data.x` contains the value of `i` from the `.each()` loop corresponding to the element that the event listener was attached to.

In this example they're the same, because the `<p>` elements are the only children of the container. But if you modify the example a little you can see the difference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").each(function(i) {
    $(this).on("click", {
      x: i
    }, function(event) {
      alert("The " + $(this).index() + ". paragraph has data: " + event.data.x);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div>This is a div</div>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<div>
  <p>This is a paragraph nested deeper</p>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

The first DIV is another child of the container, so it affects the indexes of the paragraphs after it. And the last paragraph is in a different container, so indexing starts over from `0` there.

But in all cases, the variable `i` just increments sequentially, and this is saved in `event.data.x`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed infos :))

Answer (score 0):

`event.data` is the second parameter of this line:

*$(this).on("click", **{x:i}**, function(event){*

This is how you declare an eventHandler, in simple words, you are telling what to do when someone clicks any `<p>...</p>` element, so the last parameter is the function that will run when the click happens.

When the browser detects a click, it will run this function with some data about the event that just happened, an object, that in the example you call **event**, you can check out what else this object contains here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp

### More Info

You don't have to call it **event**, you can call it anything, like:

```
$(this).on("click", {
  x: i
}, function(potato) {
  console.log(potato.data) // {x:#}
});
```

You can omit the second parameter if you don't need to use the data

```
$(this).on("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.data) // undefined
});
```

About the index vs data.x, the difference is that the **each** function, gives you an index parameter starting from 0, and the index() function of the element will probably give you

```
$("p").each(function(i) {
  $(this).on("click", {
    x: i
  }, function(event) {
    console.log(event.data.x) // 0...1...2...3 depending on where you clicked
    console.log($(this).index()) // 1...2...3...4 depending on where you clicked
  });
});
```

Comment: WOW so many detailed infos unlikely my local forums.. Thank you guys all!!